# Improvement of code performance handling large zip file

Tags: php, gitlab, php-ziparchive

I have a code that do exactly what I need. It handle a zip file that contains a repository from gitlab that's about 80mb of size.

In the code I just need to remove the "root path", and put all the files inside it in a new zip file. And it works well.

The problem is that the code is too slow doing it. Any ideas of what can be improved in this case? The code follows below.

```
$zipFilename = 'file-' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . ".zip";
$tmpDir = dirname(__DIR__) . '/temp';
$zipPath = $tmpDir . '/' . $zipFilename;

$fileZip = new ZipArchive();

if ($fileZip->open($fileZipToExtract) === true) 
{
    $newZip = new ZipArchive();
    $newZip->open($zipPath, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE | ZipArchive::CHECKCONS | ZipArchive::CM_STORE);

    $rootDir = basename($fileZip->getNameIndex(0));
    $rootDirPrefix = $rootDir . '/';
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fileZip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $fileZip->getNameIndex($i);
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($filename);

        if (strpos($filename, $rootDirPrefix) === 0 && ($fileInfo["dirname"] == "." || $fileInfo["dirname"] == "..")) {
            continue;
        }

        $basename = $fileInfo['basename'];
        $dirname = $fileInfo['dirname'];

        if (strpos($dirname, $rootDir) === 0) {
            $dirname = substr($dirname, strlen($rootDir));
        }

        if ($fileInfo['extension']) {

            if(empty($dirname)) {
                $newZip->addFile($fileZipToExtract, $basename);
            } else {
                $dirname = ltrim($dirname, '/');
                $newZip->addFile($fileZipToExtract, $dirname . '/' . $basename);
            }

            fclose($stream);

        } 
    }
    
    $newZip->setArchiveComment('File generated at ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $newZip->close();
    $fileZip->close();
```

I tried many solutions, but no success until now

Comment: This seems unnecessary, why not just download as a tar instead, and then use `--strip-components=1`?

Comment: @AlexHowansky What you mean bro? I don't know hot to use this resource you said.  I just want to remove the "root path" from the zip.

Comment: You should have the option of downloading the repository as a `*.tar.gz` instead of a `*.zip`. The `tar` command has a built-in extract option called `--strip-components` which does exactly what you're trying to do here. I.e., if you use tar instead of zip, this whole process is unnecessary.